# Sending non-protected broadcast com.motorola.motocare.INTENT_TRIGGER java.lang.Throwable

Tags: android, android-studio

I have searched different answers on stack overflow. It shows the error even if I disable the services and broadcast receivers.

This is my Manifest file:-

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.appzoy.croatiaapp">

<!-- to make api calls -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- for qr code scanning -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TicketsListActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    <receiver android:name=".receivers.AlarmReceiverSubmit"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true"/>

    <service android:name=".services.AlarmService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true"/>

    <receiver android:name=".receivers.NetworkChangeReceiver"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Whenever I close the navigation drawer `SettingsActivity` appears to foreground and this is the activity where I set the alarm using this code:-

```
 private void setAlarm(Calendar calSet) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm is set @ " + calSet.getTime(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getBaseContext(), 1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}

private void setAlarmSubmitTickets(Calendar calSet) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm is set @ " + calSet.getTime(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiverSubmit.class);
    intent.putExtra("selectedTime", txtSendTicketsTime.getText().toString());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
```

And my **Log** file is as follows :-

> 03-13 10:12:48.253 1576-22821/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.motorola.motocare.INTENT_TRIGGER from system 4512:com.motorola.process.system/1000 pkg com.motorola.motgeofencesvc
>                                                          java.lang.Throwable
>                                                              at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:18226)
>                                                              at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:18826)
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:512)
>                                                              at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2906)
>                                                              at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354717/i-always-see-e-activitymanager-sending-non-protected-broadcast-from-system-in

Comment: I have already tried this link... but this didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have in your **AndroidManifest.xml** declared `"android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"`, then declare the protected broadcast.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.yourcompany.mypackage"
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="24" />

<protected-broadcast android:name="com.motorola.motocare.INTENT_TRIGGER" />
```

**You can build with Android Studio.**

Comment: This seems to work with my Android 8.0 environment! Thanks! Alternatively, you can add the `protected-broadcast` definition to `frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml` for platform developers.

Comment: tried to put protected-broadcast in manifest, get warning "Element Protected Broadcast is not allowed here"

Comment: android:sharedUserId is constant was deprecated in API level 29.

Comment: From API level 29 you should use **uses-permission** instead of **protected-broadcast**