# E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.mediatek.log2server.EXCEPTION_HAPPEND

Tags: android, error-handling, crash-reports

I'm making an app which worked fine, but today only due to the app my phone's `SYSTEM UI` got crashed, and everytime I intsall the app, the crash goes to the infinite loop. **I have also observed that, after testing it on other phones, the app worked well, but in MOTO C PLUS, it is not**. Due to that I had to do factory reset.

I have followed the link, in order to resolve the issue, didn't work out for me : [ERROR FIX FOR MOTO PHONES](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50240471/7232944)

The app didn't run when I implemented the code, by including the same in my manifest file.

I have updated the `GOOGLE PLAY STORE`, and checked my version of the phone. Everything was updated.

I'm using firebase version `12.0.1`.

My phone `SYSTEM UI` stops responding every time I install the app **in my phone only MOTO C PLUS**.

Not using any `broadcast receiver` though, but still can' figure out why am I getting this thing. Previously I didn't get this kind of error, but now it is very difficult to open the app.

Also, I have noticed one thing, everytime I install the app, a pop comes up saying `GOOGLE PLAY HAS STOPPED WORKING`, and then this `SYSTEM UI HAS STOPPED` comes.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. I'm really struggling with this. I won't be able to test it out, if this will happen again, and again.

Also, Is there any way to uninstall the same app in my phone, by doing that I get the functionality of my phone back, but right now the whole screen is gone, just for future references.

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Hi, you found any fix for this issue ?

Comment: Yes @Shahal, I have used the small sized icon in my manifest. The icon size was too big, which was causing the crash to happen again and again.